# How to remove rounded corners on jqgrid

Tags: css, jqgrid

I am working on an application that uses trirand jqgrid on multiple pages, along with Bootstrap 3.1 and Flat UI design.

I have modified the jqgrid styling to confirm with the theme that I am using, I would like to know the simplest way to remove the rounded corners from jqgrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below to your CSS, beneath the jqGrid css:

```
.ui-corner-all, .ui-corner-top, .ui-corner-left, .ui-corner-tl, .ui-corner-right, .ui-corner-tr, .ui-corner-bottom, .ui-corner-bl, .ui-corner-br {
    border-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
    -khtml-border-radius:0;
}
```